# Python - Class instances share class dictionary variable?

Tags: python-3.x, class, dictionary, instance, instance-variables

```
class Student():

    NAME = ''
    DICT = {}

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.NAME = name
        self.DICT['name'] = name

    def change_DICT(self, change):
        self.DICT['name'] = change


student_one = Student('Leo')
student_two = Student('Liz')

print ('Student one NAME: ' + student_one.NAME)
print ('Student two NAME: ' + student_two.NAME)
print ('---------------------------------')
print ('Student one DICT: ' + str(student_one.DICT))
print ('Student two DICT: ' + str(student_two.DICT))
print ('---------------------------------')
student_one.change_DICT('Tom')
print ('Student one DICT: ' + str(student_one.DICT))
print ('Student two DICT: ' + str(student_two.DICT))


>> Student one NAME: Leo
>> Student two NAME: Liz
>> ---------------------------------
>> Student one DICT: {'name': 'Liz'}
>> Student two DICT: {'name': 'Liz'}
>> ---------------------------------
>> Student one DICT: {'name': 'Tom'}
>> Student two DICT: {'name': 'Tom'}
```

I have been playing with this for hours and still can't wrap my head around it. How does changing `DICT` of one instance of the class `Student` changes `DICT` of all other instances synchronously.

How does this happen and if I really need to use a `dict`, what is the best way to work around this?

Comment: In addition to my answer: I do find it strange that `self.DICT` can still target that class variable, though, so I am not sure why that happens. Perhaps someone else can enlighten us.

Comment: @BramVanroy `self.DICT` doesn't target that class variable, but `self.DICT['name']` does. Your code works even with `DICT` predefined. Thanks for your help! I'll mark this as a duplicate since I found what I needed in the post @Cyber Tailor suggested.

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve your desired output by changing initialization position of class attributes such as `DICT` and `NAME`.
I will give you the example.

```
class Student():


    def __init__(self, name):
        self.DICT = {}
        self.NAME = name
        self.DICT['name'] = name

    def change_DICT(self, change):
        self.DICT['name'] = change

student_one = Student('Leo')
student_two = Student('Liz')

print ('Student one NAME: ' + student_one.NAME)
print ('Student two NAME: ' + student_two.NAME)
print ('---------------------------------')
print ('Student one DICT: ' + str(student_one.DICT))
print ('Student two DICT: ' + str(student_two.DICT))
print ('---------------------------------')
student_one.change_DICT('Tom')
print ('Student one DICT: ' + str(student_one.DICT))
print ('Student two DICT: ' + str(student_two.DICT))
```

This will give output as:

```
Student one NAME: Leo
Student two NAME: Liz
---------------------------------
Student one DICT: {'name': 'Leo'}
Student two DICT: {'name': 'Liz'}
---------------------------------
Student one DICT: {'name': 'Tom'}
Student two DICT: {'name': 'Liz'}
```

Here, You would check dictionary value has been changed.

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing class variables and instance variables. When you declare a variable outside the constructor (i.e. above `__init__)` it is a class variable, meaning it is shared. Instead, you only want instance variables, as follows.

```
class Student():
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.NAME = name
        self.DICT = {'name': name}

    def change_DICT(self, change):
        self.DICT['name'] = change


student_one = Student('Leo')
student_two = Student('Liz')

print ('Student one NAME: ' + student_one.NAME)
print ('Student two NAME: ' + student_two.NAME)
print ('---------------------------------')
print ('Student one DICT: ' + str(student_one.DICT))
print ('Student two DICT: ' + str(student_two.DICT))
print ('---------------------------------')
student_one.change_DICT('Tom')
print ('Student one DICT: ' + str(student_one.DICT))
print ('Student two DICT: ' + str(student_two.DICT))
```